# Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in

Tags: php, function, stdclass

i have sometimes following error
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in..
with this function:

```
function deliciousCount($domain_name)
{
    $data = json_decode(
        file_get_contents(
            "http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/json/urlinfo/data?url=$domain_name"
        )
    );
    if ($data) {
        return $data[0]->total_posts;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

$delic = deliciousCount($domain_name);
```

but this error happen sometimes only for specific domains 
any help?

Comment: Can you tell us an example of an url that "triggers" the error? Must be something where the response from delicious.com is valid json but not of the form `[ ... ]`.

Comment: **Note**: my assumption is that the only time the error was _not_ triggered was if/when the request file_get_contents request was unsuccessful.. or whatever the case, `json_decode` will return false or null if there is nothing to decode; therefore, his function would return false thus evading the error.

Comment: domain is http://www.xcursionsindia.in sometimes happen sometimes no

Comment: This function of delicous.com is broken. For existing domains like [google.de](http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/json/urlinfo/data?url=google.de) one time you'll get an entry (`[{"url":...}]`) and other times an empty object (`{}`). For no-existing domains like [example.example](http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/json/urlinfo/data?url=example.example) `[]` *or* `{}`.

Comment: infact Saxoier you have right and so what is solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function deliciousCount($domain_name) {
    $data = json_decode(
        file_get_contents(
            "http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/json/urlinfo/data?url=$domain_name"
        )
    );
    // You should double check everything because this delicious function is broken
    if (is_array($data) && isset($data[ 0 ]) &&
        $data[ 0 ] instanceof stdClass  && isset($data[ 0 ]->total_posts)) {
        return $data[ 0 ]->total_posts;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), there is an optional second `boolean` param which specifies whether the returned object should be converted to an associative array (default is *false*). If you want access it as an array then just pass `true` as the second param.

```
$data = json_decode(
    file_get_contents(
        "http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/json/urlinfo/data?url=$domain_name"
    ),
    true
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Before using $data as array:

```
$data = (array) $data;
```

And then simply get your total_posts value from array.

```
$data[0]['total_posts']
```

Answer (score 0):

`json_decode` returns an instance of stdClass, which you can't access like you would access an array. `json_decode` does have the possibility to return an array, by passing `true` as a second parameter.

Answer (score -1):

```
function deliciousCount($domain_name)
{
    $data = json_decode(
        file_get_contents(
            "http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/json/urlinfo/data?url=$domain_name"
        )
    );
    if ($data) {
        return $data->total_posts;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

$delic = deliciousCount($domain_name);
```

or

```
function deliciousCount($domain_name)
{
    $data = json_decode(
        file_get_contents(
            "http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/json/urlinfo/data?url=$domain_name",true
        )
    );
    if ($data) {
        return $data['total_posts'];
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

$delic = deliciousCount($domain_name);
```